# CSS substring matching attribute selectors: Contains multiple class names

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

A CSS "contains" selector is

```
td[class*="foo"]
```

I can select multiple classes with

```
td[class*="foo bar"]
```

This however will fail for `<td class="foo baz bar" />`

How can I do a CSS "contains" wildcard select?

*BTW: I cannot use `td.foo.bar`*

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? It seems working to me http://jsbin.com/wufot/1/edit Though that's not the correct way of selecting the classes.

Comment: @HashemQolami is right.Can you give an example where it fails?

Comment: `td[class~="foo"][class~="bar"]` will match `<td class="foo bar">` exactly and will not match `<td class="foobar bar">`

Comment: My bad - I meant it would fail for `<td class="foo baz bar" />` - I updated the question

Comment: Is there a specific reason you cannot use class selectors over attribute selectors? Are you working with a markup language that does not have class semantics in the form of a `class` attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The selector you're looking for is as follows, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28309152/1470607) for more details.

```
td[class*="foo"][class*="bar"]
```

However, if you need to use selectors like that then it's often a sign that your class name logic is bad.

Comment: I'm using it on media queries in email css. I would prefer to use different selectors but from what I know this is the only way to get it to work.

Comment: I would recommend against using `*=` for class names and other delimited values for the reason stated in Hashem Qolami's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly I don't know what you mean by "failing" `td[class*="foo bar"]` selector as it [seems working](http://jsbin.com/wufot/1/edit) to me in your particular case.

However, since the class names are separated by white spaces, you could use multiple `[attr~=value]` [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select the elements having the classes as follows:

```
td[class~="foo"][class~="baz"] {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wufot/2/edit)**.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> `[attr~=value]` Represents an element with an attribute name of `attr`
>   whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is
>   exactly "value".

Comment: My bad - I meant it would fail for `<td class="foo baz bar" />` - I updated the question

Comment: yes, `td[class~="foo"][class~="baz"]` works perfectly. What the difference to `td[class*="foo"][class*="bar"]`?

Comment: @Horen You are welcome. Using `[class*="foo"]` my cause unexpected issues as it selects `<td class="foobar">` element as well. As andyb mentioned in his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385993/css-substring-matching-attribute-selectors-contains-multiple-class-names/22386156?noredirect=1#comment34032120_22385993).

Comment: @Horen Take a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/wufot/4/edit). Toggle the selectors to see the difference.

Comment: @Horen: The only way for `~=` attribute selectors to work where class selectors wouldn't in your case is if you were not actually working with HTML...

Answer (score 4):

### Visit : [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) (*CSS Attribute Selectors*)

From the above for finding a match of a given string to the string in the class specified according to your question , the only option I find working and correct is `*` and `~`.

> ## 1. [Demo for *](http://jsfiddle.net/69Ymj/)
>
> [image: * CSS-selector]
>
> ## 2. [Demo for ~](http://jsfiddle.net/69Ymj/1/)
>
> [image: ~ CSS-selector]

---

### Multiple attribute matches

[image: Multiple attribute]

Comment: You might as well post this in a comment instead.