# CSS difference between attribute selectors with tilde and star?

Tags: css

Given the following CSS selectors

```
[attribute~=value] { }
[attribute*=value] { }
```

Should both of the selectors above do exactly the same thing? Or is there a difference?

I believe that there is some kind of a difference, but what? The only one which I spot is that the first of each pair is in the spec of CSS 2 and the second in spec of CSS 3.
Is there anything else?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4g0vx5t2/2/)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[The asterisk attribute selector `*=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax) matches any substring occurrence. You can think of it as a string contains call.

| Input | Matches `*=bar` |
| --- | --- |
| `foo` | No |
| `foobar` | Yes |
| `foo bar` | Yes |
| `foo barbaz` | Yes |
| `foo bar baz` | Yes |

[The tilde attribute selector `~=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax) matches whole words only.

| Input | Matches `~=bar` |
| --- | --- |
| `foo` | No |
| `foobar` | No |
| `foo bar` | Yes |
| `foo barbaz` | No |
| `foo bar baz` | Yes |

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}


[attribute*=bar] {
  background: lightgray;
}

[attribute~=bar] {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>no attribute</div>
<div attribute="foo">attribute="foo"</div>
<div attribute="foobar">attribute="foobar"</div>
<div attribute="foo bar">attribute="foo bar"</div>
<div attribute="foo barbaz">attribute="foo barbaz"</div>
<div attribute="foo bar baz">attribute="foo bar baz"</div>
```

Answer (score 32):

The `~=` is called [Attribute Contains **Word** Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/).

So when you use: `[attrName~=stuff]` it will match every element that has `attrName`'s value **equal to** `"stuff"` or containing `"stuff "`, `" stuff "` or `" stuff"`. Examples:

- Selector: `[name~=ball]`
- Matches:

  - `<input name="ball" type="text">`
  - `<input name="ball " type="text">`
  - `<input name=" ball" type="text">`
  - `<input name=" ball " type="text">`
  - `<input name="doesnotmatter ball asLongAsballIsBetweenWhiteSpaces" type="text">`

---

The `*=` is called [Attribute Contains **Substring** Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

When you use `[attrName*=stuff]` it will match if `stuff` is present in the attribute's value, even if inside some word, such as:

- Selector: `[name*=ball]`
- Matches:

  - All those that were matched by `[name~=ball]`, but also...
  - `<input name="whatball" type="text">`
  - `<input name="ballwhat" type="text">`
  - `<input name="whatballwhat" type="text">`
  - and so on, as long as the attribute's value *contains* the string `ball`.

---

Note: the links above point to jQuery's website just because, for those specific selectors, I find their reference to be the best, but those attribute selectors are from **[CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors)** and **[have been supported since IE7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Browser_compatibility)**.

MSDN also calls the contains word selector [Whitespace Attribute Selector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358832(v=vs.85).aspx).

Finally, **[<kbd>click here for a demo fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/uychwqpj/)**.

Answer (score 10):

`Regular expression` equivalent:

- [attribute`*=`value] *==* /value/
- [attribute`~=`value] *==* /`\b`value`\b`/

Comment: Haha, super concise. Best answer.